# Use Google Sheets to ping IP addresses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Google Sheets**

Cell Range A1:A99 contains IP Addresses

Cell Range B1:B99 contains True/False if address can be reached

**Objective**
Use Google Apps Script to pull the values from the first cell range. If those values can be pinged, then populate the second cell range with True.

Can this be done with Google Apps Script?

Comment: If "Ping" refers to issuing an ICMP Ping, then it's not possible to do this, as GAS doesn't support low-level OS operations. You could instead try to reach a HTTP service at those addresses via UrlFetch - a different type of connectivity is being tested. Of course, all addresses must be on the internet, not an intranet, as it would be Google's servers attempting to connect.

Comment: @exceptUserError - was wondering if you needed any help with this or if you were able to figure this out? As indicated in the previous comment, this could easily be achieved using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).