# How can I ping a specific IP using Google App Script?

Tags: networking, google-apps-script, ping

I want to ping a specific ip address using GAS. I tried using **UrlFetchApp.fetch()** but it's says unable to fetch url as i don;t have any html content hosted on that specific ip. So, how can i check the pings to decide wither the ip is live or down ?

Comment: Potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764719/use-google-sheets-to-ping-ip-addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot ping an IP with Apps Script via ICMP. However, there are a few things you can try with `URLFetchApp`

Instead of looking for returned HTML content, look at the response code.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(yourIP, { 
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  validateHttpsCertificates: false,
  followRedirects: true 
});

var siteStatus = response.getResponseCode();
```

If you get a response code that is not 0, there is a server there listening (afaik, correct me if wrong). An example: using `104.16.34.249` (Stackoverflow) will return 403, which is a forbidden status code. There is a site there and you tried to access content you are not authorized to access. If you use `192.0.78.9` (wordpress.com) you recieve a status code of `200` which means the request has succeeded.

List of status codes: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html